# ace editor make cursor blink after selecting a new line

Tags: wysiwyg, ace-editor

It's probably a realy simple question for someone allready familliar with ace, but after i move the editor to a new line by using

```
editor.gotoLine(row, col);
```

How could i animate the cursor(make it blink like when you manually select a new line) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ace cursor blinks only if editor is focused. If you want to force blinking on blurred editor, you can use private renderer.$cursorLayer object by calling

```
editor.renderer.$cursorLayer.isVisible=true;
editor.renderer.$cursorLayer.restartTimer();
```

or

```
editor.renderer.$cursorLayer.showCursor()
```